# Java Menu without JButtons Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: multithreading

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.argusstudios.Name.Main.render(Main.java:90)
    at net.argusstudios.Name.Main.run(Main.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

That's the error I get when I try to run it, I'm trying to figure out how to make a menu system without JButtons because I dislike them. But when I run the program this happens, just trying to get the class Menu to run, which isn't working sadly.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 700;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 560;
    public static int SCALE = 3;
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public static Dimension size = new Dimension(700, 560);


    public static String name = "name";

    private enum STATE{
        MENU,
        PLAY,
        OPTIONS
    };

    private STATE state = STATE.MENU;

    //State new classes
    private Menu menu;
    private Options options;

    public void init() {

    }

    public Main() {
        setPreferredSize(size);
    }

    public void start() {
        isRunning = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Main component = new Main();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(component);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle(name);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        component.start();
    }

    public void tick() {
        if(state == STATE.PLAY){

        }
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        //Put Rendering in here before dispose :P

        //Title screen background rendering
        g.setColor(new Color(80, 40, 100));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        if(state == STATE.PLAY) {

        } else if(state == STATE.MENU) {
            menu.render(g);
        }

        //No Rendering past here.
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(isRunning) {
            tick();
            render();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yea sorry Line 90 is menu.render(g); in the

      if(state == STATE.PLAY) {

        } else if(state == STATE.MENU) {
            menu.render(g);
        }

Comment: Editing your question (and don't use **Edit**, or **Update** in the text while doing so, as we have edit history), with additional information, is preferred over hiding useful details in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You never instantiate your menu variable. You need to instantiate before you call it via:

```
menu.render(g);
```

So either in your init or start methods instantiate your menu with the proper constructor, for example:

```
menu = new Menu("Main Menu");  //Or whatever parameters your menu takes.
```

Comment: Yea I did Its in the init method

*edit Whoops I put up the wrong one, just a sec